# SQL Insert values by join

Tags: sql, join, insert

Perhaps it's too late and that's why I am stuck. I want to fill a database with values but only for those values where a date already exists in the data base. The structure is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TEST(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,date_time datetime)

ALTER TABLE dbo.TEST ADD "column1" FLOAT;

INSERT INTO dbo.TEST(date_time,"column1")
  VALUES ('2018-04-01 02:00:00',1),('2018-04-01 06:00:00',2),('2018-04-01 07:00:00',3) 

ALTER TABLE dbo.TEST ADD "column2" FLOAT;
```

so the table looks like this:

[image]

now I want to fill column2 for 2:00 and 6:00 o clock with the values 20 and 21 but ignore value 25. What I have is

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TEST("column2")
        SELECT
            NewValues."column2"
        FROM (
          VALUES  ('2018-04-01 02:00:00',20),
                  ('2018-04-01 06:00:00',21),
                  ('2019-10-05 20:30:00',25)
              ) AS NewValues(date_time,"column2")
        INNER JOIN dbo.TEST
        ON dbo.TEST.date_time = NewValues.date_time
   WHERE dbo.TEST.date_time = NewValues.date_time
```

but this results in

[image]

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an `update`:

```
update t
    set column2 = NewValues.column2
    from dbo.TEST t left join
         (values  ('2018-04-01 02:00:00', 20),
                  ('2018-04-01 06:00:00', 21),
                  ('2019-10-05 20:30:00', 25)
              )  NewValues(date_time, column2)
        ON t.date_time = NewValues.date_time;
```

Comment: thanks for that. For completeness I added a "WHERE t.date_time = NewValues.date_time" at the end, as otherwise all values of the column are getting replaced. I use the statement in a python for loop so when using your approach onley the values from the last iteration are left in the column.